# Calling destructor when doing assignment operation

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, assign

In my following function a new Object of `MyClass` is created and assingned to `myObject`. After that the destructor of the new Object is called. The original object declared in outside the function is NOT destroyed. `MyClass` has the dafault assignement operator.

```
MyClass myObject; //global varibale;

void somefuction()
{
    myObject = MyClass();
}
```

My Question is: Is there a way to store a new object in `myObject`, so that the orginal object is destroyed, without using pointers.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to get around the assignment operator not being implemented correctly. Why should `myObject` be killed? Its value is changed.

Comment: Are you following [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: How are you determining that which object is destroyed? `myObject`'s address will never change

Comment: ok so i implement the assignement operator to destroy all objects that will be overwritten?

Comment: Assigning is not supposed to destroy the object that's being assigned to. It should just give it a new value. If you have some operations in the destructor that you need to do in order to implement assignment, you should do those in an overloaded assignment operator as well, not destroy the object.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to do something in this direction

Comment: Why do you want myObject to be destroyed ? It will when it will go out of scope (if you are not using pointer).  So what is its scrope ?

Comment: I implemented the assignement operator, but that brought up a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335619/assignement-operator-changing-value-the-assigned-object